# pywinauto изменение размера окна

Tags: python, pyqt5, pywinauto

Читал документацию и нашел лишь такой способ изменить размер окна с помощью pywinauto, но он к сожалению не работает. Буду рад если кто то сможет помочь

```
app = Application(backend="uia").start(f"{os.getenv('APPDATA')}\\Telegram Desktop\\Telegram.exe")    
dlg = app.window()
dlg.maximize()
```

Comment: Насколько я помню, десктопный Телеграм вообще не поддаётся нормальной автоматизации. Скорее всего это сознательное решение разработчиков. Ведь есть Python клиент для их API через web. Так что я бы сказал, сам путь - не тот. :)

Comment: Ну, и рекомендация для новичков на StackOverflow: фраза "не работает" мало что говорит, надо приводить полный дамп ошибки (весь traceback), в питоне он очень о многом говорит. Впрочем, наличие кода в вопросе - уже хоть что-то.